# Method missing in User model, Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model

This should be easy but I'm obviously missing something. Working through a testing exercise, and attempting to create a method on the User model. Seems like it should be incredibly straightforward, but Rails is throwing method missing whenever I attempt to access the method.

Here's the code for the file app/models/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_secure_password

  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  def administrator?
  end
end
```

At this point I'm working through TDD process, and only attempting to satisfy the test exception by creating the method (I'll add code for the administrator? method later). Here's the line from the spec:

```
    expect(admin.administrator?).to be_true
```

And the output from the test:

```
1) User management adds a new user
 Failure/Error: expect(admin.administrator?).to be_true
   expected  to respond to `true?`
```

However, I can't seem to access the freaking method! Whenever I call the #administrator? method on an object of the User class I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `administrator?' for #<User:0x007f9ac6929358>
```

Here's the pry response to 'ls -M' when I'm in the User class, showing the methods available:

```
User#methods: administrator  password  password_confirmation
```

Here's the output from a pry console session:

```
[73] pry(User):1> admin = User.first
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 1, email: "test@yahoo.com", password_digest: "secret123", created_at: "2015-06-25 17:33:25", updated_at: "2015-06-25 17:33:25", admin: true, firstname: nil, lastname: nil>
[74] pry(User):1> admin.valid?
User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."email" = 'test@yahoo.com' AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1
=> true
[75] pry(User):1> admin.instance_of?(User)
=> true
[76] pry(User):1> admin.administrator?
NoMethodError: undefined method `administrator?' for #<User:0x007f9ac6929358>
from /Users/me/.rbenv/versions/2.1.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activemodel-4.1.1/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:435:in `method_missing'
```

I've tried defining the method as self.administrator as well, with the same results. I went back and looked at the model methods defined in the Rails Tutorial, and I can't see anything about Hartl's model that helps me understand why my method isn't working.

Any help would be appreciated! I'm missing something basic here it seems...

**** EDIT/UPDATE ****
After getting a response about how to return the boolean :admin column from the user object I realized that it's worth clarifying the real question. The real issue I was trying to understand isn't so much whether the `administrator?` method is the best way to determine whether a given user is an admin or not (as @sajinmp very helpfully points out below, the object will respond to `admin?` because of the corresponding column in the database).

My real question/frustration was with why I couldn't get the object to respond to that or any other methods created in the model.

Comment: Have you definitely tried to restart the rails server and/or reload the console?  Doesn't seem like it should be necessary...  not sure where method `administrator` is getting defined - I am wondering if that is a clue of some sort.

Comment: Thanks Steve! I almost always cycle the server when I encounter any issues, but it didn't occur to me to do that in this case, since I could use `reload!` in the console session to reload the app. After cycling the server it started responding to the method calls.

Comment: Not sure myself @scrodaddy but those are my go to steps when I enter the Rails twilight zone (strange symptons like you were facing).  Great to hear you are past it.

Answer (score 1):

If all you are doing in the method is to check whether a user is an admin or not you do not need such a specific method. Since in your user model the administrator is represented by admin simply calling admin? is enough.

```
current_user.admin (<admin.admin> in this case)
```

will answer your call. But when admin is nil this will be a problem so it is better to use

```
admin.try(:admin)
```

This will not throw an error even if admin is nil.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I realized after reading it that the real question was: "Why isn't the object responding to any method calls?", not "How do I determine if the user object is an admin?" Since this was an exercise I was trying to define a method rather than use the boolean :admin column defined in the model. Cycling the server seemed to fix it...

Comment: Aah. So you did not restart the console once you added the method? That would indeed result in error which would be solved once you reload it.

Comment: No I actually had restarted the console, and also called "reload!" I didn't think the server would cause any issues if I was working in the console, but after restarting the server it worked. Thanks again

Comment: Thank you. It was a new info for me.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted the Rails server, and that seemed to fix it. After cycling the server and starting a new console session, the user object now responds to the methods in user.rb.

Should have done that sooner (DUH!), but I'd assumed that it wouldn't be necessary. Within the console session I could use `reload!` and then the Pry `show-source` method would confirm that the methods were appearing in the console as written. I didn't think that the console relied on the server, but I must be wrong..?

Appreciate any confirmation on this.